# LAX 1 hour connection T7 to T6 - is this doable?

Tags: transit, lax

Hi we are travelling on rewards points and for some reason the connection time through LAX is only 1 hour.  Arriving from KONA with United in the early AM (Terminal 7) and departing to Toronto (Terminal 6) with Air Canada.

Last time we did this I think Air Cda was in a different terminal and we had to go though security and it was very tight.

Is this doable?

Comment: There are about 5 Air Canada flights/day LAX to Toronto. So, you will still get there the same day even if you misconnect, and since it is a single ticket, they have to rebook you.

Answer (score 1):

From [United's map of LAX](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/airport/maps/lax.aspx)  there is a secure walkway from terminal 7 to terminal 6 (see the dotted line on the image)

[image]

Thus you will not have to exit and re-enter security when changing terminals.  So a 1 hour connection should be OK.

---

On a personal note, I once landed at Terminal 4, and followed the signs to Tom Bradley (via the dotted lines) and kept wondering "Where is security? I'm supposed to go through security to get into TB!  Am I headed in the right direction?!?!?"